# Oracle ADF::How do I pass a parameter to named query via requestScope to another view object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, oracle-adf

Question::
    How can i pass the value to parameter named “userParameter” in a query. using requestScope
    Kindly help out with the steps to make a request scope work on the same page.

For now I know the following.

1. I have a page named UserRoomReservation
2. I have a data control (UserView)
   Drag the first data control as a table.
   convert the first column to a link
   add actionlistener to that link
   from: #{row.userId}
   to: #{requestScope.userParameter}
3. I created another view object via sql query
   I put a named parameter ":userParameter"
   the sql query is as written below:::

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT Fullreservation.USERID,
          Meetingrooms."roomName",             
          Meetingrooms."roomId" ,
          COUNT (Fullreservation.roomid) AS countRoomUsage
   FROM FULLRESERVATION Fullreservation, "meetingRooms" Meetingrooms
   WHERE fullreservation.roomid = Meetingrooms."roomId"
   AND Fullreservation.USERID = :userParameter

   GROUP BY
          Meetingrooms."roomName", 
          Meetingrooms."roomId",
          Fullreservation.USERID
   ```
4. I dragged it to the same page as a graph.
   but it doesn't work because the value hasn't been passed to the

Answer (score 0):

You can get value from requestScope

```
ADFContext.getCurrent().getRequestScope().get(obj);
```

and then set this value in bind variable using NamedWhereClauseParam method

```
ViewObjectInstance.setNamedWhereClauseParam("BindVariabbleName",value);
ViewObjectInstance.executeQuery();
```